# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptors'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, interceptor

Adding the following code to my `applicationContext.xml` file gives me the above error.

```
<!-- Configuring interceptors based on URI -->
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/home" />
        <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor"></beans:bean>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

**The error is:**

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptors'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, 
 WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.`

Pardon me if it is a very simple question.

Comment: Show your complete `applicationContext.xml`